# is mockito uses reflection api to mock objects

Tags: java, reflection, mocking, mockito

Mockito is used to mock the objects for unit testing. Same can be done using java reflection API. Does this mean Mockito is implemented on reflection API of java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Mockito doesn't use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, which [only works on *interfaces*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). (Even if it did, I'd be wary of logic that says "A can be used for B, that means library L used A for B".)

To allow for more flexible mocking, including mocking of concrete classes, Mockito generates bytecode for its mocks using:

- [CGLib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib)/[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)/[Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/) for Mockito prior to 2.0 [[source](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker.html)]
- [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) for Mockito from 2.0 onwards
- [DexMaker](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker) to create .dex files for Android Dalvik VMs (since 1.9.5)
- arbitrary implementations of [MockMaker](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker.html) to support other platforms and packages (since 1.9.5)

For what it's worth, the CGLib Proxy class that Mockito used was designed to be a [drop-in replacement for java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Proxy.html).

---

Side note: Mockito definitely uses Java's reflection API, such as to refer to the Method object in [InvocationOnMock.getMethod](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html#getMethod()). This is probably not what you meant by "used to mock the objects", though.